# Emulating a strict/uninterruptible for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a toy language that compiles to C++ as an exercise. I'm trying to add an OCaml/Pascal/Fortran-style `for` loop with an index variable, a lower bound and an upper bound.

A C-style `for` loop, however, is more general than this. It allows the loop variable to be modified and requires the body of the for loop to be executed sequentially in order because you might `break`, `return`, throw an exception, call `goto` &c, not to mention side effects.

My understanding is that C++ compilers are good at optimizing cases where you use a C-style `for` loop but just-so-happen not to `break` or modify the loop variable &c. I'm trying to find a way to encode the strict `for` loop I want into C++ in such a way that doing these things is actually undefined behavior according to the C++ standard and, ideally, in a way that existing implementations of C++ can exploit.

The closest example I can come up with is*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i) {
  [](const int i) noexcept {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }(i);
}
```

but `noexcept` is not strict enough. If an exception is thrown, then `std::terminate` is called ... which means that reordering the execution of the body is not a legal optimization.

*The `const` is technically unnecessary here. It's just there to make modifications of the "fake" loop variable a compile-time error.

Comment: What about trying to detect this in the compiler for your own language?  For the index variable, your parser could try to rule out at least assignment, increment / decrement, passing by reference, and perhaps taking the address of it.

Comment: Your solution is pretty good. However, there is no definite way to detect runtime exceptions on compile time. You could, for example force the loop closure to be a constant expression, and therefore, it would never `throw`.